# Why does the amateur implementation of a Fortran version of Delphi's TStringList behaves 10 times lower than Delphi's built-in one?

Tags: string, performance, delphi, memory-management, fortran

To learn the OO feature of latest `Fortran`,  a `Fortran` version of `Delphi`'s `TStringList` is written and linked below (`gist.github`). The `Fortran` source mimics the `Delphi` one.

This `Fortran` `TStringList` functions as expected. My problem is, however, its LoadFromFile/SaveToFile combination to read/write a 30MB file is 10 times slower than Delphi's counterpart. The larger the file is, the worse the Fortran's version looks. I wouldn't be surprised because of my amateur Fortran skills. For the same reason, I could not understand where the performance drop happens or even where to start. Could you help to comment? Thank you very much for your time!

[System.f90](https://gist.github.com/3dd70d740a3e372a3415)

[SysUtils.f90](https://gist.github.com/347d4f5e3d1ce8eff5a4)

[Classes_TStringList.f90](https://gist.github.com/4010199758d1e976b0c8)

[Test program of the LoadFromFile/SaveToFile](https://gist.github.com/631152d69bef02262431)

Comment: @Mike B: Thank you for your time! My intention was, because I don't know about the reasons, one can just copy & paste the very code, compile and run. (Also, this `Fortran` version of `TStringList` functions well, and thus might be useful for other people. :P)

Comment: It's also incomplete. It may be too much to fit into the question text. If the source is online somewhere, link to it, if not put it online somewhere. (e.g. https://gist.github.com/ )

Comment: The two functions that matter most (maybe the only ones that matter here) - LoadFromFile and SaveToFile have been truncated from your question. Without seeing them, one explanation would be if Delphi is using buffered I/O and the Fortran version isn't.

Comment: @Stijin Sanders: Thank you for your suggestion! Sorry that I didn't notice the truncation... Now the code is on `gist.github.com` as you suggest.

Comment: @hatchet: Thank you for your comment! In LoadFromFile/SaveToFile, the reading/writing plays with the whole file in one call. Could you help to comment whether buffered I/O matters here?

Comment: @XichenLi - after seeing your code, I don't think buffered i/o is the explanation since you're reading the whole file into a buffer in one operation. So something else is the cause. I think this is where profiling comes in. The best way to know where your code is spending its time is by profiling it. From that you could see if everything is 10 times slower in your Fortran version (i.e. it's Fortran's fault), or if you've introduced a bottleneck in your implementation.

Comment: @hatchet: Thank you for your comments! I wonder how I should profile practically? Do I need to insert timing calls to every methods of TStringList of both Fortran and Delphi? I would imagine there are tons of output due to the amount of internal calls.

Comment: That will work in a pinch but search around to see if there is an instrumenting or sampling profiler that supports your compiler implementation.

Comment: @XichenLi - if you can't find suitable profilers, you can do it the laborious way. There are a couple approaches. One is to think what's fundamentally different between Fortran and Delphi and test that. Example- print the time to compare two average length strings 100,000 times and see if that's the culprit. Or go top down. Test the time to insert 100,000 strings into a list. If Fortran & Delphi times very different, test each part of what insert does separately and compare those. But good profiling tools will save you from having to drill down to the answer.

Comment: @Kenneth Cochran: Thank you for your comment! I have been searching around, though my Fortran knowledge really lags me off...

Comment: @hatchet: Thank you very much for your suggestions! I will try to compare the functions. (This might take a while because there are quite a few functions and this is just one class :D)

Comment: Pay attention to memory operations in your code. Delphi has memory manager, that speeds up them a lot - FastMM4. But even without it, core classes manage memory very efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the most fundamental difference will come from the different nature of the "String" type in Delphi and variable length character strings in Fortran-90.

In Delphi, a String is a reference type.  Not only that, but it is also a reference counted and copy-on-modify type.

That is when you write:

```
  var
    a, b: String;   
  begin
    a := 'The quick brown fox';
    b := a;

    b := b + ' jumped over the lazy dog.';
  end;
```

When **a** is assigned to **b** there is no copying of string characters.  Instead **b** and **a** are pointers that now reference the same character string with a reference count of 2.

When **b** is then modified, it is only at that point that the code is generated (by the compiler) that is required to create an initial, duplicate string with it's own reference count (1) and to decrement the reference count from the original.

However, simply adding a string to a list obviously does not modify it.

When **TStringList** reads the contents of a file, a string is read from the file.  When the string value is then added to the internal list, the string itself is not copied but instead the reference count is merely increased, reflecting the fact that even when the "LoadFromFile" method is no longer using that string (because it's contents have been replaced by the next string read from the file) the one previously added to the internal list item remains valid.

**LoadFromFile** must then initialise a new string ready to receive the next string from the file, but this is unavoidable.

The difference is that in the Fortran version, in addition to initialising each string as it is read from the file, each of those strings must also be copied at the point at which the item is added to the list.  This copying of string data is eliminated in the Delphi code thanks to the reference counted string type.

Fortran code therefore will be unavoidably less efficient, and the greater efficiency of the reference-counted String type in Delphi will have an impact in almost every area of a class that is - by definition and design - a heavy "user" of this string type.

This will be over and above and in addition to any additional relative differences in the performance of the memory management or code generation efficiencies of the Delphi compiler vs Fortran.